# How to find out if there is a record based on select query?

Tags: ms-access, vba

In my code I am doing some batch editing to records in one Access table and add new records. However before adding new records I need to check if there is already such records by checking several fields, if they exist then nothing is done, if there is no such records, then editing and adding is done.
here is the code for checking part:

```
Set myR2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("_tbl_FILimits_", dbOpenDynaset)
'If the recordset is non-empty, exit.
myR2.FindFirst ("[LimitType] =" & chooseLimitType & "And [ReviewDate] =" & setDate)
If myR2.NoMatch Then
    MsgBox "There is no such period exists, proceding next..."
    updateRecords myR, myArray
Else
    MsgBox "!!! Choose different review date. ALready exists such period! Quitting..."
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my silly mistake. I forgot to enclose the date with ##.
so if I change the 3rd line to this one:

```
myR2.FindFirst ("[LimitType] =" & chooseLimitType & "And [ReviewDate] =#" & setDate &"#")
```

the code worked as intended.